# TCPIP connection not working in matlab

Tags: matlab, tcp, printf

Can any body help me out with the problem I am facing while making a tcpip connection with an instrument.Its like when I make a connection with the tcpip address using the following it works perfectly fine for any no of times.

1.test and measurement tool(TMTOOL in matlab)
2.Zoc terminal
3.teraterm.

but when I try to implement the following script its does run but dont know some how doesn't seem to send the command to the pan and tilt unit which I am tryin to control.

I am trying with two scripts:

A.

```
obj1=tcpip('169.254.32.28',4000);
fopen(obj1);
cmd=5000;
fprintf(obj1,'pp%d',cmd)
fclose(obj1);
delete(obj1);
```

I am trying to send a command pp5000

B.

```
%commands
lat=51.57668;
lon=-1.26765;
alti=500;
% Find a tcpip object.
obj1 = instrfind('Type', 'tcpip', 'RemoteHost', '169.254.32.28', 'RemotePort', 4000, 'Tag', '');

% Create the tcpip object if it does not exist
% otherwise use the object that was found.
if isempty(obj1)
    obj1 = tcpip('169.254.32.28', 4000);
else
    fclose(obj1);
    obj1 = obj1(1)
end

% Connect to instrument object, obj1.
fopen(obj1);
i=1;
tic
for i=1:10
% Communicating with instrument object, obj1.
fprintf(obj1, 'gg%f,%f,%f',lat,lon,alti);

i=i+1;
toc
end
fclose(obj1);
delete(obj1);
```

Desired result:

gg51.57668,-1.26765,500

The second script is just a little bit modified version of the automatic script generated from TMTOOL im matlab

Basically I want to print some commands on the desired object every half a second.

can anyone suggest some alternative or improvement that could be done to achieve the desired results.

I have been unable to execute these scripts and I think it should be correct with whatever small knowledge of matlab I have.I am a new user and I would appreciate if you could help.

Thanks

Salil

Comment: There are a lot of things that can go wrong when trying to communicate across a network. Have you tried playing around with the built in echo server?  Have you tried writing up your own simple  echo server? I'd personally start by getting those to work and then add complexity to the problem after.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the Java classes (sockets) to pass data back and forth, it how I do it.

File 1:

```
import java.net.ServerSocket
import java.io.*

server_socket = ServerSocket(4000);
client_socket = server_socket.accept;
out = PrintWriter(client_socket.getOutputStream, true);
in = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(client_socket.getInputStream));
str = in.readLine(); % Read in data
out.println(data); % send data
```

File 2:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
server_socket = Socket('localhost', 4000);
in = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(server_socket.getInputStream));
out = PrintWriter(server_socket.getOutputStream,true);
```

Get and send input the same way as above. When you're done don't forget to close everything.

```
out.close();
in.close();
client_socket.close();
server_socket.close();
```